# How to import npm module in JavaScript stimulus

Tags: javascript, npm-install

I want to use `imageToZ64()` from [zpl-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zpl-image) module

I have installed it using: `npm install zpl-image`

and then I import it: `import './../../../node_modules/zpl-image';`

but when I use the fucntion like this  `let res = imageToZ64(canvas);`
 i'm getting : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: imageToZ64 is not defined

I tried to import it like this: `import { imageToZ64 } from  './../../../node_modules/zpl-image/zpl-image';`

but the problem is this function uses other functions from pako.js which is another js file in the zpl-image.
my question is how to import the module in a way that I can be able to access all the functions?

Comment: `const { imageToZ64 } = require("zpl-image");` Should do the work. Also reading about [import-export](https://javascript.info/import-export) will help in long run

Comment: thanks but now I'm getting this error as I expected : main.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: pako is not defined
    at t (main.js:66)
    at imageToZ64 (main.js:66)
    at main.js:28       it can't acess pako.js file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you read the README here : [zpl-image repo GitHub](https://github.com/metafloor/zpl-image#requirejs-browser-usage)

In order to use this with Node.js :

```
const imageToZ64 = require("zpl-image").imageToZ64;
```

Or :

```
const { imageToZ64, rgbaToZ64 } = require("zpl-image");
```

If you are trying to use it in the browser read [generic browser usage](https://github.com/metafloor/zpl-image#generic-browser-usage)
since you already installed it via npm there is a demo file in `node_modules/zpl-image/zpl-image.html` ,you can open it in the browser, read its content, and understand how the code works which is the purpose of the demo file.

Comment: i've tried both but i'm still getting : main.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: pako is not defined
    at t (main.js:66)
    at imageToZ64 (main.js:66)
    at main.js:28       it can't acess pako.js file !

Comment: OK , can you please edit your question and provide more information : code you have wrote , your project setup , and what are you trying to do, so i can investigate further on why you are getting this errors

Comment: i really can't figure out why you are getting this error  since you didn't provide more  informations , if you're trying to use zpl-image in the browser i already edited the answer .

Comment: I added the JS scripts references to my HTML page just to try and suddenly it works! I can access the functions from my controller now I don't know how this helped actually ! ,, Thanks WaLid !

Comment: You are welcome, please do not forget to mark this answer  as **Accepted**